# ruby erb - why template on the server side?

Tags: ruby, erb

I am learning ruby and have just run into the .erb file extension. Why would you want to template on the server side as opposed to using javascript (e.g. underscore or handlebars)?

All I want out of ruby is a simple server side language that can handle CRUD database actions for my application. If I have to use ruby's templating solution I might see it as a dealbreaker and stick with php.

Comment: Ruby is not tied to erb templates in any way. If you want to use ActiveRecord and Rails to make a data server, there is nothing that stops you from configuring your actions to serve json instead of html.

Comment: @cheesetaco: How is this any different from the views in a PHP MVC framework? ERB templates look a lot like PHP templates, just compare `<?php echo $thing; ?>` to `<%= @thing %>`, it's almost the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either erb or JavaScript template engines. It has nothing to do with Ruby. If you are using erb, that is parsed by Ruby, and since a web browser cannot handle Ruby, it has to be on the serverside.